# Partial search on date fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-date

I'm trying to implement partial search on a date field in elastic search. For example if startDate is stored as "2019-08-28" i should be able to retrieve the same while querying just "2019" or "2019-08" or "2019-0".

For other fields i'm doing this:

```
{
            "simple_query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "customer"
              ], 
              "query": "* Andrew *",
              "analyze_wildcard": "true",
              "default_operator": "AND"
            }}
```

which perfectly works on text fields, but the same doesn't work on date fields.

This is the mapping :
{"mappings":{"properties":{"startDate":{"type":"date"}}}}

Any way this can be achieved, be it change in mapping or other query method? Also i found this discussion related to partial dates in elastic, not sure if it's much relevant but here it is:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/45284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [ES-Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified)
> and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

It is not possible to do searching as we can do on a text field. However, we can tell ES to index date field as both date & text.**e.g**

**Index date field as multi-type:**

```
PUT sample
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "year_month_day",//<======= yyyy-MM-dd
        "fields": {
          "formatted": {
            "type": "text", //<========= another representation of type TEXT, can be accessed using my_date.formatted
            "analyzer": "whitespace" //<======= whitespace analyzer (standard will tokenized 2020-01-01 into 2020,01 & 01)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST dates/_doc
{
  "date":"2020-01-01"
}

POST dates/_doc
{
  "date":"2019-01-01"
}
```

**Use wildcard query to search:** You can even use n-grams at indexing time for faster search if required.

```
GET dates/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "date.formatted": {
        "value": "2020-0*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote & accept as answer if it answers your question.

Comment: It works perfectly. I however made a few addition and changes so that i can have a uniform mapping throughout.

{"startDate":{"type":"date","fields":{"formatted":{"type":"text","analyzer":"standard"},"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}

This mapping can be used for the other fields too, incase someone is trying to implement filtering on multiple columns.

Comment: this is the only working solution I found after searching for a very long time.

thank you